# pip installing does not install to virtualenv

Tags: python, django, terminal, pip, virtualenv

I'm very new to all of this, so bear with me.

I started, and activated, a virtual environment. But when I pip install anything, it installs to the computer, not the the virtual env.

I'm on a Mac, trying to build a Django website.

Example:
With the virtual machine activated. I type:

```
python -m pip install Django
```

Then I can deactivate the virtual env, and type:

```
pip freeze
```

And it will list out the freshly installed version of Django.

Any clue as to why this is happening?

Comment: Did you already create a virtualenv directory? e.g. `virtualenv venv` where `venv` is the virtual environment? then `source venv/bin/activate`

Comment: Thanks! I was using a different virtual env or something. I pip installed virtualenv, set up a new env, activated it, and that seems to work.

Comment: You pip installed virtualenv but if you are using python3, virtualenv is embedded. `python -m venv .venv`, where `.venv` is the virtualenv name. Then, `. .venv/bin/activate` and you should be all set for `pip install` ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Run this line from your project folder where "env" is your virtual enviroment

```
# A virtualenv's python:
$ env/bin/python -m pip install django
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install to your virtualenvironment you have to activate it, otherwise it will install to the main folder.

Comment: Yup, I do have it activated when I'm installing things.

Comment: does it say something like `(venv)` at the bottom of your console?

Comment: Yup, when activate, each line in terminal starts with (env)

Comment: that means that the packeges will be installed to your `env` folder, try again

Answer (score 0):

Confirm you’re in the virtual environment by checking the location of your Python interpreter, it should point to the env directory.

On macOS and Linux:

```
which python
.../env/bin/python
```

As long as your virtual environment is activated pip will install packages into that specific environment and you’ll be able to import and use packages in your Python application.

Comment: ahhh, okay. I typed in "which python" with the virtual env activated, and again with it deactivated, and they both have the same exact path: '/usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin/python'

Comment: I think there is some error regarding activation of venv . Follow the guide https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtual-environments/#:~:text=venv%20will%20create%20a%20virtual%20Python%20installation%20in%20the%20env%20folder.&text=You%20should%20exclude%20your%20virtual,your%20version%20control%20system%20using%20. regarding proper creation and activation of virtual environment

Comment: I ended up pip installing virtualenv, activated that, and that seemed to have done the trick. Thanks for your help!

Comment: If your problem is solved , please mark it answered :)